# Plot multiple 3D images in a single plot window with plot3d

Tags: r, plot, rgl

When I plot several 3D images using `plot3d` from the `rgl` package, the images are displayed separately. I want to show them in one plot, as when using, e.g., `par(mfrow=c(2, 2))` to display four 2D images in a single plot window.

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at the `plot3D` package (and e.g. the examples at `?plotdev`, `?scatter3D` etc.). They won't be interactive (draggable) like those produced by `rgl`'s `plot3d`, though.

Comment: Thanks @jbaums, I have tried that,but it's not what I want.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you're after, exactly. Do you expect to be able to rotate/etc. the plots with the mouse, or are you happy with snapshots of particular views? If the latter, what elements can't be achieved with the `plot3D` package?

Comment: It's not use the plot3D package, I want to use the plot3d of rgl package to show several 3d images in a single plot. @jbaums

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want. By "3d images", do you mean you want them to be interactive (i.e. able to be rotated with the mouse, etc.)? This question will get more attention if you edit it and be very clear about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am sorry if this is not clear.Not interactive or rotation, just want to know if the plot3d of rgl can plot two or more 3d images in a single plot. I said 3d images, because several 2d images are easily plotted in a single plot using par(mfrow=c(2,2)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command *layout3d* might be useful. Maybe this code can help:

```
 shapes <- list(Tetrahedron = tetrahedron3d(), Cube = cube3d(), Octahedron =  octahedron3d(),
 Icosahedron = icosahedron3d(), Dodecahedron = dodecahedron3d(),
 Cuboctahedron = cuboctahedron3d())
 col <- rainbow(6)
 open3d()

 mat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
 mat <- rbind(mat, mat + 4, mat + 8)
 layout3d(mat, height = rep(c(3, 1), 3), sharedMouse = TRUE)
 for (i in 1:6) {
 next3d()
 plot3d(shapes[[i]], col = col[i])
 next3d()
 text3d(0, 0, 0, names(shapes)[i])
 }
```

To deactivate the rotation of all the solids together, it is enough to put *sharedMouse = FALSE*.

Comment: Thanks, Matteus. That's what I want to find.